# Logical operator causing compile-time error on functions called

Tags: c++, logical-operators

This question might have been answered before, but searching around and using google didn't bring me there, so I'll ask.

I'm currently making a game and working on collision, however, for some reason it seems like whenever I try to compile I get a `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`

At first I thought I might have something wrong in my syntax which I checked, but wasn't able to find anything, so I just left the line of code to this:

```
if((getMinX() > c->getMinX()) && (getMinX() < c-getMaxX()))
```

I tried adding `this->` or adding parenthesis, but that doesn't seem to work, however, just doing

```
if(this->getMinX() > c->getMinX())
```

seems to work fine as well as

```
if((5 > 3) && (5 < 10))
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Both objects are derived from a class called Collideable defined like this

```
class Collideable
{ public:
    bool collidesWith(Collideable*);
    virtual int getMinX() = 0;
    virtual int getMaxX() = 0;
    virtual int getMinY() = 0;
    virtual int getMaxY() = 0;
};
```

All classes properly override from the virtual methods and the code causing the issue is in `bool Collideable::collidesWith(Collideable* c)`

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/ the logical operators return a boolean value (which makes sense to me, coming from Java) so what's causing this problem?

Comment: @wallyk Ahhh.... I feel stupid now, I can't believe I made such a little mistake... Thank you

Comment: Wow, lots of redundant parentheses to make the code harder to read. `if ((5 > 3) && (5 < 10))` is the same as `if (5 > 3 && 5 < 10)`.

Comment: I know, I added the parenthesis as part of debugging, I'm aware that they aren't needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to know if this is what is in the program or a simple transcription problem:

The first line is written ending as  `c-getMaxX()`;  maybe it should be `c->getMaxX()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have `c-getMaxX()` but you need `c->getMaxX()`, with a `>`.

Comment: I can't accept both answers but yours is correct, thank you